# Episerver 6 property with condition

Tags: episerver

This get; How do I adjust this get set to work in a class that inherits from TypedPageData (Episerver 6)

```
[PageTypeProperty(
 EditCaption = "Caption",
 HelpText = "Hint here",
 Type = typeof(PropertyUrl),
 Tab = typeof(ComposerTab))]

     public virtual string Property1 { 
      get 
      {
       if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Property1.ToString()))
        return "http://www.blabla.com";
       return "sdfsdf";
      }   
      set { Property1 = value; } 
     }
```

At the moment it has no value.
Probably to do with how properties are defined in Epi? Thanks

Comment: This is actually PageTypeBuilder-specific, typed page types weren't introduced natively until Episerver 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
public virtual string Property1 { 
      get 
      {
       if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.GetPropertyValue(page => page.Property1)))
        return "http://www.blabla.com";
       return "sdfsdf";
      }   
      set { this.SetPropertyValue(page => page.Property1, value); } 
     }

`
```